# build後に「分割したファイル内容を変更した場合」でも、build結果に反映させたい

Tags: go

[リンク先](https://qiita.com/suin/items/f4ad02e4123c8a3c75eb)内容で、
1.build実行
2.build実行後に、foobar.go ファイルの関数内の Hello world を Good morning へ変更

・go run main.go 実行すると、Good morning と表示されますが、
・build結果を実行すると、Hello world と表示されます

---

**Q.上記内容で、build結果を実行して、Good morning と表示させるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？**
・分割したファイル全てをbuildするのではなく、メインファイル(main.go)だけをbuildして、分割ファイル(foobar.go)内容はbuild後も随時変更内容を反映させたいのですが…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

基本的に`go build`でコンパイルした場合、buildしたファイルに、build以降のソースコードの変更を反映させることはできません。
なぜなら、`go build`でコンパイルした結果作成されたバイナリファイルは、実行時にソースコードを読んでいないからです。
コンパイル後のバイナリは、ソースコードと独立して動作します。

変更を反映したバイナリがほしければ、`go build`でもう一度buildする必要があります。